# azure_rm Ansible plugin fails to parse dynamic inventory

Tags: azure, ansible, yaml

I'm unable to create an Ansible dynamic inventory for Azure. I get the following error:

```
bash-5.1# ansible-inventory -i inventory_azure_rm.yaml --graph -vvv
ansible-inventory [core 2.12.2]
  config file = /playbook/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-inventory
  python version = 3.9.7 (default, Nov 24 2021, 21:15:59) [GCC 10.3.1 20211027]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = False
Using /playbook/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
toml declined parsing /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml with script plugin: problem running /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml --list ([Errno 13] Permission denied:
'/playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 290, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/script.py", line 150, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError(to_native(e))
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml with auto plugin: name 'client_secret' is not defined
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 290, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/auto.py", line 58, in parse
    plugin.parse(inventory, loader, path, cache=cache)
  File "/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 219, in parse
    self._credential_setup()
  File "/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 240, in _credential_setup
    self.azure_auth = AzureRMAuth(**auth_options)
  File "/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 1522, in __init__
    self.azure_credential_track2 = client_secret.ClientSecretCredential(client_id=self.credentials['client_id'],
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 290, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/yaml.py", line 112, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError('Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory')
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a port.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 290, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/ini.py", line 136, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError(e)
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
```

The `inventory_azure_rm.yaml` file is:

```
plugin: azure.azcollection.azure_rm
auth_source: credential_file
plain_host_names: yes
include_vm_resource_groups:
  - <redacted>
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.applicationRole
    separator: ""
```

The `ansible.cfg` file is:

```
[defaults]
inventory = inventory_azure_rm.yaml

[inventory]
enable_plugins = host_list, script, auto, yaml, ini, toml
```

Ansible Azure collection version

```
bash-5.1# ansible-galaxy collection list

# /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections
Collection         Version
------------------ -------
azure.azcollection 1.11.0
```

I would appreciate any help on trying to solve this.
Thank you.

---

Update:

- Fixed `inventory_azure_rm.yaml` file permissions.

  ```
  bash-5.1# ls -la inventory_azure_rm.yaml
  -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           200 Feb 24 17:27 inventory_azure_rm.yaml
  ```
- Updated the error stacktrace on the problem description running the command again.

---

Update2:

The Azure `credentials` file looks like this:

```
bash-5.1# cat ~/.azure/credentials
[default]
subscription_id=<redacted>
client_id=<redacted>
secret=<redacted>
tenant=<redacted>
cloud_environment=AzureCloud
```

Comment: Could you throw a `ls -la inventory_azure_rm.yaml` and show us what this yields?

Comment: This is the output (I'm testing in a container): 
`-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           200 Feb 24 17:27 inventory_azure_rm.yaml`

Comment: That's probably it. Your inventory does have execute permission, which is absurd for a text file. `chmod -x inventory_azure_rm.yaml`.

Comment: I added the execute permissions on purpose because if not, I get another error instead of the `[Errno 8]` posted above. The error is `[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml with script plugin: problem running /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml --list ([Errno 13] Permission denied:
'/playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml')` - but still, the `Invalid host pattern 'plugin'` error is there.

Comment: That permission denied has nothing to do with permission on the file.

Comment: So, your issue at hand here is because you added that execute flag, correct this, and adapt your question to make it [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Updated. Thank you for your help, @β.εηοιτ.βε

Comment: From the next error, it seems like your `secret` is not defined in your file _~/.azure/credentials_: _[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /playbook/inventory_azure_rm.yaml with auto plugin: name 'client_secret' is not defined_

Comment: Yes, I saw that but the `credentials` file has the `secret` entry. I've update the problem description with a bit more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the problem on parsing the dynamic inventory. I was doing the following:

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt && \
ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection:1.11.0
```

I've changed 2 things:

- Invert the order on installing the collection and its dependencies. First I need to install the `azure.azcollection` and after that, its dependencies.
- Install the `azure.azcollection` dependencies from the `requirements.txt`  coming with the collection itself instead of doing it from Github.

This is the code working:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection:1.11.0 && \
pip install -r ~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt
```

The difference between the `requirements.txt` file from GitHub at `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt` and the local `requirements.txt` file at `~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt` is on `azure-mgmt-network` package version. The online version is `19.1.0` and the local (working) version is `12.0.0`.

```
bash-5.1# diff -w requirements-azure.txt ~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt
--- requirements-azure.txt
+++ /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@
 azure-mgmt-monitor==3.0.0
 azure-mgmt-managedservices==1.0.0
 azure-mgmt-managementgroups==0.2.0
-azure-mgmt-network==19.1.0
+azure-mgmt-network==12.0.0
 azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
 azure-mgmt-privatedns==0.1.0
 azure-mgmt-redis==5.0.0
```

Comment: I didn't understand this until I saw the Issue in GitHub. Basically I needed to downgrade to an older version. Thanks!
https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues/771